# How to append latest output result to text file without repeating output again and again

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

I want to get job status output with latest executed time to the text file , however when I run the job each time ( schedule using cronjob )
It’s appending old, executed result also in the text file as well, but I want to get text output with latest executed result only .
How to overcome this issue .

Example :

```
#!/bin/bash
ydate="$(date +"%H-%M-%S")"
echo "${ydate} Test1   Done " >>/app/my_status.log 2>>/app/my_status.log.err
echo "${ydate} Test2   Done " >>/app/my_status.log 2>>/app/my_status.log.err
echo "${ydate} Test3   Done " >>/app/my_status.log 2>>/app/my_status.log.err
echo "${ydate} Test4   Error " >>/app/my_status.log 2>>/app/my_status.log.err
echo "${ydate} Test5   Not_Running " >>/app/my_status.log 2>>/app/my_status.log.err
```

when I execute script each 5 minutes, I get result like below

```
14-41-14 Test1   Done
14-41-14 Test2   Done
14-41-14 Test3   Done
14-41-14 Test4   Error
14-41-14 Test5   Not_Running
14-46-15 Test1   Done
14-46-15 Test2   Done
14-46-15 Test3   Done
14-46-15 Test4   Error
14-46-15 Test5   Not_Running
14-51-15 Test1   Done
14-51-15 Test2   Done
14-51-15 Test3   Done
14-51-15 Test4   Error
14-51-15 Test5   Not_Running`
```

But I want to get only 5 lines with latest time like below after last execution result

```
14-51-15 Test1   Done
14-51-15 Test2   Done
14-51-15 Test3   Done
14-51-15 Test4   Error
14-51-15 Test5   Not_Running`
```

echo out the result without appending

Comment: At the start of your script, cat /dev/null to your file to clear it out. Or you could add a timestamp to your file name and avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: @Scott Hoffman Output file name can not be change , as this file reading from another script or program , need old result present in the file and only update during latest execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to truncate then. Use a grouping.

```
#!/bin/bash

ydate=$(date +"%H-%M-%S")

{
    echo "${ydate} Test1   Done"
    echo "${ydate} Test2   Done"
    echo "${ydate} Test3   Done"
    echo "${ydate} Test4   Error"
    echo "${ydate} Test5   Not_Running"
} >/app/my_status.log 2>/app/my_status.log.err
```

You can also use `exec` to open a file and use a file descriptor for the whole session. Just look around for examples.

Comment: Thanks it's working as expected .

Comment: would you please elaborate how to use **exec** usage related to this question @konsolebox

Comment: The key is that `>>` cretes or appends but `>` creates or overwrites. So the minimal fix to your original code would be to change its first `>>` (and `2>>`) to `>` (and `2>`). This answer is similar but better because it avoids duplication.

Comment: Adding `exec >log 2>err` somewhere redirects (and truncates) stdout and stderr. After that, `echo text` (with no redirection) will append to `log` and `echo text 1>&2` will append to `err`.

Comment: @chamara See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226164/45197. Basically you open a file for writing using exec, use the fd multiple times and then close the fd. Example: `exec {ofd}> out.log {efd}> err.log; echo "..." >&"$ofd" 2>&"$efd"; ...; exec {ofd}>&- {efd}>&-`. Consider reading the [Redirections section of the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Comment: btw, commands that already write to both stdout and stderr won't need explicit redirection (`1>&2`redirects stdout to stderr) after the `exec`.eg. `ls; ls -e` would automatically print a file listing to `log` and an error message to `err`

Comment: @chamara Does the script/ptogram that reads the file run concurrently with the script that writes to it? Then it should be prepared to find an incomplete file, e.g. missing or even partial lines.